# Wordpress remote get function usage?

Tags: wordpress, curl

I want to share and display my latest content with wp_remote_curl function for other web pages.

```
        <?php $response = wp_remote_get( 'http://feeds.feedburner.com/fatihtoprak/blog' );
                if( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
                   echo 'Couldnt get the contents!';
                } else {
                  // echo $response['body'];
                    echo '<pre>';
                print_r( $response );
                echo '</pre>';
                }
            ?>
```

The output is [here](http://pastebin.com/eNcZepqx).

Here is my wp_remote_get content codes. The question about how can I **only display title and post link in output**.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serkan is right.

From the first paragraph on http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/fetch_feed

> Retrieves an external feed and parses it. Uses the SimplePie and FeedCache functionality for retrieval and parsing and automatic caching.

Answer (score 0):

Fatih, Why you don't use `fetch_feed`
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/fetch_feed

Comment: Serkan i think its better way (wp_remote_get) because wp_remote_get means Curl in php. I ll exmine your suggestion. also could you tell me why i should use fetch_feed ?

Comment: becasue you ask about feed. fetch_feed already written and bult-in function for wordpress. You can get title and link with this function easily.

Comment: its allright but is there any cache system in thşs function / class something. Because, if fatch_feed make request alltime, that means need to get more hosting CPU